# I can't print the info in doc file in a sequence when I read the inf from the Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, documentation

The output format should be like this in the doc:

[image: Document Output]

This is the input format of the excel sheet:

[image: Excel Output]

I'm trying to read an Excel sheet and trying to print the information in a systematical order in the Word document. I can read from the Excel sheet but couldn't print it in the doc file. What should I do?

It's showing the last line of the Excel file i.e, its only over-writing the doc file but not appending it. Is there a way to append this file?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File src = new File("convertion java.xls");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
    HSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    String[] header = new String[4];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        header[k] = sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(k).getStringCellValue();
    }
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.docx"));
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            result = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(i).getStringCellValue();
            doc = header[i] + " = " + result;
            System.out.println(doc);
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraph.createRun();
            paragraphOneRunOne.setText(doc);
            document.write(out);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    wb.close();
    out.close();
}}
```

I expect the output to append the doc file but not to over-write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new `XWPFDocument` for each cell found in the `Excel` sheet. That cannot lead to the result you wanted. To get your wanted result, only **one** `XWPFDocument` is needed which then gets filled with paragraphs according the contents of the found `Excel` cells.

And for the `Excel` part, you should use the `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*` rather than `HSSF` since this is more general and also able reading `XSSF` (`*.xlsx`) then.

And you should not rely on `getStringCellValue` since not all`Excel`cell contents must always be text. Instead you should use `DataFormatter` to get the cell contents from the `Excel` cells.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

class ReadExcelWriteWord {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("convertion java.xls"));
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.docx");
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  Row row = null;
  Cell cell = null;
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = null;
  XWPFRun run = null;

  String[] header = new String[4];
  row = sheet.getRow(0);
  if (row != null) {
   for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    cell = row.getCell(k);
    header[k] = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
   }
  }

  String result = "";
  String doc = "";
  for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
   row = sheet.getRow(j);
   if (row != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     cell = row.getCell(i);
     result = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     doc = header[i] + " = " + result;
     System.out.println(doc);
     paragraph = document.createParagraph();
     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setText(doc);
    }
   }
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   System.out.println();
  }

  workbook.close();
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```